Aggregate function SUM of columns from joined / included tables using Sequelize
I have a 'CartItem' model like this:
Many(Book) < - CartItem -> Many(User)

And CartItem also has 'quantity' column.
I want to form an Order and I figured I might as well pull total price of an order like this:
const result = await this.userRepository.findByPk(ordererId, {
    attributes: [
        [Sequelize.literal('SUM("books"."price" * "books->CartItem"."quantity")'), 'total'],
    ],
    group: ["User.id", "books->CartItem.id"],
    include: [ { model: Book, attributes: [] }],
});

I can get AVG price of books by making books attributes empty.
I can't do the same for CartItem's attributes at it's "not related" to Books or Users.
But using CartItem field requires me to add "books->CartItem.id" to GROUP BY which results in getting wrong value (of only 1 cart item).
How should I change my approach?
Should I just pull cart items and calculate sum with code?

So I found the solution, you can remove attributes of CartItem using 'through.attributes' option in 'include'
And not group by cart item id
const result = await this.userRepository.findByPk(ordererId, {
    group: ["User.id"],
    attributes: { 
        include: [
            [Sequelize.literal('SUM("books"."price" * "books->CartItem"."quantity")'), 'cartPrice'],
        ]
    },
    include: [ { 
        model: Book, 
        through: { attributes: [] }, 
        attributes: [],
    }],
});

Result:
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Albert",
    "email": "albert@gmail.com",
    "createdAt": "2024-04-27T04:53:19.064Z",
    "updatedAt": "2024-04-27T04:53:19.064Z",
    "cartPrice": "62500"
}

